# How to return grpc error in nodejs

Tags: node.js, grpc

I want to return grpc error code and description in server-side. I have tried this

```
function sayHello(call, callback) {
  callback({error: {code: 400, message: "invalid input"});
}
```

but I got this exception from client

```
{ Error: Unknown Error
    at /home/thanh/email/node_modules/grpc/src/node/src/client.js:434:17 code: 2, metadata: Metadata { _internal_repr: {} } }
```

If I **don't** want to include error field in message definition like this.

```
message Hello {
  string name = 1;
  string error = 2; // don't want this
}
```

Then what is the proper way to send grpc error back to client ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change it to:

```
return callback({
  code: 400,
  message: "invalid input",
  status: grpc.status.INTERNAL
})
```

Comment: I would like to note that the `code` field won't do anything here. If you want to be propagated to the client, you need to add it to the error `metadata`. And if you want the semantics of HTTP error code 400, I would recommend using the corresponding gRPC status: `grpc.status.INVALID_ARGUMENT`.

Comment: I don't know why but it only works for me when I remove `code` and `status` and leave `message`. anyone know why ?

Answer (score 3):

As a supplement, GRPC only allowed 16 kinds of error. You can check all error code from its site: https://grpc.io/docs/guides/error/#error-status-codes.

And here I found an example code for NodeJs error handling:  https://github.com/avinassh/grpc-errors/blob/master/node/server.js

Answer (score 0):

To clarify what @avi and @murgatroid99 have said what you want to do is structure you callback like so:

```js
import * as grpc from '@grpc/grpc-js';

try{
  somethingThatThrowsAnError();
}catch(e){
  return callback(
    {
      message: e ,
      code: grpc.status.NOT_FOUND
    },
    null,
  )
}
```

`grpc.status.NOT_FOUND` is just a integer, 5, and when the client gets an error response from the server you can read it off the `err` prop returned e.g.

```js
const client = new MyServiceConstructor(
  address,
  grpc.credentials.createInsecure()
);

client.myMethod(
  myRequest,
  metadata ?? new grpc.Metadata(),
  (error: string, response: T_RESPONSE_TYPE) => {
    if (error) {
      if(error.code === grpc.status.NOT_FOUND) {
        return handleNotFound(error, myRequest)
      }

      return unknownError(error, myRequest)
    }

    return response
  },
);
```